# Download HTML Page in C#

Tags: c#, html, url

I am writing an app in c#,
Is there a way to download a HTML page by giving my program its URL only.
Foe example my program will get the URL www.google.com and download the HTML page?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [WebClient.DownloadString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Avoid this. It's painfully SLOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW (even using the proxy=null trick)

Comment: alternative for this Filipe?

Answer (score 8):

Use the WebClient class.

This is extracted from a sample on the msdn [doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public static string Download (string uri)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();

    Stream data = client.OpenRead (uri);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    data.Close ();
    reader.Close ();
    return s;
}
```

Comment: How about some using statements? The above code is not disposing the WebClient.