# Url request on RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I want to get HTML code to be displayed in a RichTextBox. I am using the code

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] data = client.DownloadData("http://www.google.com");
richTextBox1.Text = data.ToString();
```

How can I do this?

Also: I don't know why but this shows me "System.Byte[]" on the RichTextBox.

Comment: Simple search in google will find that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118860/download-html-page-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows `System.Byte[]` Because it is show the description of `data`, not `data`'s contents. to do this do something like:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        byte[] file = client.DownloadData("example.com");

        File.WriteAllBytes(@"example.txt", file);

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("example.txt");

        richTextBox1.Text = lines;
```

To see the actual content

**EDIT**

Or you can do `WebClient.DownloadString` like @Ria Suggested. Only I would implement it like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var data = client.DownloadString("example.com");
richTextBox1.Text = data.ToString();
```

Or to be more efficient even

```
richTextBox1.Text = client.DownloadString("example.com");
```

Comment: So, in order to display the bytes as a string I need to save it as a file first??? (I've already read about the DownloadString solution) Thanks by the way

Comment: @user1091856 That is one way to do it if you are storing lots of data, but `WebClient.DownloadString()` is much more efficient, see edits.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx) that downloads the specified resource as a `String` or a `Uri`:

```
var contents = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

**Note** that: `RTF` encoding is different from `HTML`. You cannot do this straight away. I suggest `WebBrowser` control.

or try this ways:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/XHTML2RTF.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/htmlrichtextbox.aspx